# Is mountaineering a sport or an adventure?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question is as simple as it seems but the answer may have some serious consequences for people who are doing it or are responsible about it as an organization or club of mountaineering.

Comment: Unless this question is a somewhat difficult way to ask "Can I ask about mountaineering on Sports SE?", _I_ don't see why it was migrated to Sports meta. I suggest remigration.

Comment: Anyway can I ask about mountaineering in sports SE?!

Comment: @aufkag See original question. "This question, if not for the purposes of defining the site's scope, is primarily opinion-based."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mountaineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountaineering) may be classified as an [adventure sport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_sport#Examples_of_extreme_sports).

> Extreme sports (also called action sports, aggro sports, and adventure sports) is a popular term for certain activities perceived as having a high level of inherent danger. These activities often involve speed, height, a high level of physical exertion, and highly specialized gear.
>
> [...]
>
> Activities categorized by media as extreme sports differ from traditional sports due to the higher number of inherently uncontrollable variables. These environmental variables are frequently weather and terrain related, including wind, snow, water and mountains. Because these natural phenomena cannot be controlled, they inevitably affect the outcome of the given activity or event.

Perhaps of interest:

> The UIAA organises [Ice Climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_climbing) as a **competition sport**. Our athletes compete in international events such as the World Cups, World Championships and continental championships. Our aim is to get Ice Climbing included in the Winter Olympic Games and to develop new competition sports. We are committed to fair play, Anti Doping and protection of the environment. [My bold.]

<sup>[UIAA](http://www.theuiaa.org/competitions.html)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent information. ;)